# Convert string to datetime object without strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

So if you don't tell Python how to output a time, it does this:

```
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
>> 2019-06-07 13:07:55.777035
```

To read a time string into a datetime object, you usually use  `.strptime()` method and tell it what it is looking for.

I know there are libraries like `dateutil` which are not part of the standard Python built-in libraries which can interpret a date string. Given that this particular string was created by standard Python without specifying anything at all about how it should be, can Python, with no non-builtin libraries get it back into a `datetime.datetime` object without telling `strptime()` what to look for?

Comment: but why not dateutil, the builtin libraries will need some format string to look up to I think

Comment: But if you do it without a `print`, you will get `datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 7, 13, 18, 30, 390232)`. It is already a datetime object.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I know you **can** do it with dateutil and you can specify a `strftime`, but I think dateutil does a little guessing and and just thought there might exist just one kind of string format which Python can read without specifying `strftime` although all others need it. @vurmux it is to do with input/output, retrieving a string from somewhere and turning it back into a `datetime.datetime` object.

Comment: @cardamom the string will get generated according to the string format you pass to strftime, it cannot guess the string format you want to use

Comment: Ok @DeveshKumarSingh I know it can't guess but don't you think there might be 1 special format that it recognises?

Comment: You can choose one of your liking and use it Or just do `'{}'.format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) ` which will give you `'2019-06-07 13:31:55.864508'`

Comment: ...but can Python get that string back into a datetime object without telling how to, that is the question

Comment: I don't think so, since there is no catch-all format string defined to convert any string to datetime object

Comment: You keep saying `strftime` but you really mean `strptime`, right? Going from a string to a datetime?

Comment: Yes, fixed that in the question

Comment: Starting with Python 3.7, there is the `datetime.fromisoformat()` method, but it is only intended as the inverse of `datetime.isoformat()` so it will only parse the standard Python ISO 8601 format output that is not quite the same as the string in your question. For example, it will parse a datetime string like  _2019-06-07T13:51:15.342289_

Comment: Thanks @benvc that is exactly what I was thinking might exist, but for now using Python 3.5 and have only ever used up to 3.6.x. Well it seems correct that they should put that in there.

Comment: Correcting part of my earlier comment, `datetime.fromisoformat()` should also parse the string in your question as it can handle some minor variability in the time part of the string. From the docs: _this function supports strings in the format(s) `YYYY-MM-DD[*HH[:MM[:SS[.fff[fff]]]][+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]]]`, where * can match any single character_.

Comment: If I'm reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 correctly, a compliant datetime string can use either "T" or space for its time delimiter. So even though `2019-06-07 13:07:55.777035` contains no T, this does not disqualify it from being an ISO 8601 datetime. I would expect `fromisoformat` to parse it successfully, and continue to do so for the foreseeable future.

Comment: I think that you need to tell Python if it is a T or a space. Was noticing in the Pyhon 3.7 docs it says "New in version 3.6: %G, %u and %V were added." and I think with the G you can get it to parse ISO 8601 in one hit.

Comment: You don't need to tell Python if it's a T or a space if you use `fromisoformat`. The %G, %u and %V directives are for strftime/strptime, and have no bearing on fromisoformat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. While `datetime` outputs in this consistent format, the module does not seem to have a trivial way to read that same format back in (e.g. a format string constant). Moreover, `strptime()` doesn't have a default for its format argument, so we must specify one. However, doing so is very straightforward:

```
x = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
```

and you could easily make that format string into a constant that you use throughout your program (and it's fine to hardcode this - this format is a standard, it's not going to change):

```
utc_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f"
...
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, utc_format)
```

---

Theoretically you could also use string slicing or regex to extract the year, month, day, etc. explicitly, but then you'd still have to manually construct a datetime object out of all that, and there's no good reason to go through the trouble when datetime exists. I don't believe there's anything else in the standard library that can do it better.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Python 3.7 or later, [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) will parse datetime strings in one of the ISO 8601 formats emitted by the built-in methods (including the datetime string in the question). From the docs:

> Return a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) corresponding to a *date_string* in one of the formats
>   emitted by [`date.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) and [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).
>   Specifically, this function supports strings in the format(s)
>   `YYYY-MM-DD[*HH[:MM[:SS[.fff[fff]]]][+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]]]`, where
>   `*` can match any single character.
>
> **Caution:** This does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it
>   is only intended as the inverse operation of [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).